# How to change svg (<g>) height?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

How do I change the height of a g element?

```
height = {params} doesn't want to react
```

I threw off my work in the comments, since the svg is very large (Scene.js)

```
{/* Scale man */}
      <g transform="translate(320,388)" viewBox="0 0 351 450">
        <g transform={`translate(336,0) scale(-1, 1)`}>
          <g transform="translate(30.25,179)">
            <g>
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="351"
                height="450"
                viewBox="0 0 351 450"
              >...<
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-mountain-7kb7o?file=/src/man.js:27110-27490

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You have a height attribute on the svg why are you not adjusting that.  g is a non-rendering element so probably height is not a valid attribute for it, it will take the height of its contents

Comment: The height of a group will depend on the shapes it contains. One way to change the height of the group would be adding a rectangle inside. However if you need a viewBox you may want to transform the group in a nested svg element. Please edit your question with more details about what you want to achieve.

Comment: While you are learning SVG also learn to use: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ because with **M123.987862** precision you are effectivly pushing 1 **million** "design" pixels into 1 screen pixel.. a very bloated SVG file

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, [`<g>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) cannot have a `height` or `viewBox` attribute.

I'll assume you are trying to clip the `<g>` to that `viewBox`.

One approach is to use an `<svg>` tag, which does support `viewBox`:  (You might need to move the transform into a child element.)

```js
{/* Scale man */}
      <svg transform="translate(320,388)" viewBox="0 0 351 450">
        <g transform={`translate(336,0) scale(-1, 1)`}>
          <g transform="translate(30.25,179)">
            <g>
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="351"
                height="450"
                viewBox="0 0 351 450"
              >...<
```

Another approach is to use [`<clipPath>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) to explicitly clip the group via `<g clip-path="url(#myClipPath)">`.  But this is more annoying because it requires a separate definition of `<clipPath id="myClipPath">`.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a css transform on it and adjust the scale till you get the required height.

```
transform: matrix(scale, 0, 0, scale, 0, 0);
```

Eg:

```
transform: matrix(1.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 0, 0);
```